# Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in '... » eslint-config-standard': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, eslint

I've been trying to use ESLint along with Standard and I haven't been able to get it to work. I've tried setting it up through eslint --init, uninstalling eslint globally and having all the packages locally, installing each package manually `npm install --save-dev eslint eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-standard eslint-plugin-promise eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-node`, reinstalling ESLint extension and nothing so far. I'm perfectly able to run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix ...` in order to fix/check errors but it doesn't work with the VSCode extension by any meanings. I don't have prettier so it isn't related to it either.

Output:

```
[Info  - 12:33:20 AM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 12:33:23 AM] ESLint library loaded from: c:\Users\h08FXplsV8\Documents\dev\node\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-prisma\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
[Error - 12:33:25 AM] 
Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'graphql-prisma\.eslintrc » eslint-config-standard': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'
Require stack:
 - C:\Users\h08FXplsV8\Documents\dev\node\graphql-bootcamp\__placeholder__.js
Happened while validating C:\Users\h08FXplsV8\Documents\dev\node\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-prisma\src\resolvers\index.js
This can happen for a couple of reasons:
 - The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file (e.g. .eslintrc).
 - If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure 'eslint-plugin-import' is installed globally as well.
 - If ESLint is installed locally, then 'eslint-plugin-import' isn't installed correctly.
```

.eslintrc:

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "standard"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

I've seen other questions in SO related to this issue but none of the solutions worked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue for many weeks and finally found this thread and comment on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/696#issuecomment-542592372

My issue turned out to be related to subdirectories.  As soon as I made the project the only open project with an .eslintrc.js file, all of my linting issues went away.

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @mike-stevens I found that setting `eslint.workingDirectories` to `"mode": "auto"` lets me load my entire mono-repo in vscode and eslint works in each project. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/696#issuecomment-561732898

Answer (score 13):

To fix the dependency tree, try following [these steps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app) in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

Comment: I completed the steps and then restarted my IDE. It worked after the restart. Hard to say which was the solution, though.

Comment: It works for eslint 8.45.0 version.
For one thing, I skipped the third step as I had no babel packages.

Comment: It works for me perfectly with version `"eslint": "^8.56.0",`

Answer (score 12):

Also, be sure, that you have **latest version** of "eslint-plugin-import" plugin, as in my case, for example i had this error with "2.20.1" version, but latest "2.25.3" solved this issue

Comment: In my case it has partially helped, but then I had a problem with other libraries. In the end I simply updated npm and node.js, and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error caused by the **eslint-plugin-import** dependency and in my case, I got rid of the error by increasing to the latest version of the package.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this issue too which was why I checked this post but did not see any answer that work for me. After searching online, I stumbled into this code which solves my problem.

```js
npm i -D eslint @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

For those having the following error with flutter firebase cloud functions after running `firebase init functions` and trying to run `firebase deploy --only functions`:

```
ESLint: 8.9.0
 
Error: Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'es-abstract/2021/RequireObjectCoercible'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\xx\Documents\xx\xx\functions\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\ExportMap.js
- C:\Users\xx\Documents\xx\xx\functions\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\rules\named.js
- C:\Users\xx\Documents\xx\xx\functions\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\xx\Documents\xx\xx\functions\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs
```

This was solved by:

- delete node_modules in functions folder
- delete package-lock.json in functions folder
- `cd .\functions\` in the terminal to get into functions folder, run `npm i`, `cd ../`
- `firebase deploy --only functions`

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of Node you are running. I also had this issue and remembered I was running a much more current version of Node for a previous project. After downgrading to a matching version with the current project, it worked just fine. Here's an excellent solution for managing Node versions, BTW.

https://github.com/tj/n

Answer (score 0):

As other answer suggested, updating "*eslint-plugin-import*" might help, but in my case it lead to another incompatibility, and then another one. In the end I reverted changes and simply **updated npm and node.js** to newest version. This resolved the issue! It's possible that some libraries conflict still existed, but newer version of these 2 handled it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

For my project, a mono repo with nested `package.json`s, I needed to make sure any listed `eslint` dependency was of the same version, in my case `8.38`, rather than `8.38`, `8.58`, `8.44`, etc.

I believe that with different versions of eslint scattered over your mono repo, `eslint` will be confused in where to look for the plug-ins.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i was not using jest at all.

So i had to downgrade de eslint dev dependency:

```
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
```

as it say here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15149#issuecomment-939501275

Answer (score -1):

Check and delete unexpected `.eslintrc.json` files in parent directories.

I accidentally generated a project in a parent directory, erased the project files but because system files (prefix `.xxxx`) were hidden from my finder I couldn't see it existed.

Answer (score -1):

It worked to commit and push when I removed the pre-commit and pre-push files in .husky file.

I don't added the change to my commit, but this helped me push the changes needed.